# Is there a python way of serially searching a string with regexes, akin to java's re.appendReplacement and appendTail

Tags: python, regex

I cannot find a way to serially search a string and append replacements. Let's say I am implementing a templating language. A simplified template looks something like this:

> Hello words on #DATE# in #COUNTRY# on this beautiful day.

Imagine a very long template, with many `#SOMETHING#` tags. Now I want to use regex to parse through this, and every time I found `#SOMETHING#`, do some python logic, replace it with some string, append it, and continue. All I found is that I can break the string up into tokens and matches and then reassemble it. Is there something better, without generating all those string chunks? Maybe I am trying to optimize too early, but in Java, we have the

```
appendReplacement(StringBuffer,String) and appendTail(StringBuffer)
```

methods and I was wondering if something similar can be done in Python.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/matcher.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a function as the "replacement" in `re.sub`.  Then `re.sub` will invoke your function for every match in the string, and the return value of the function will be the replacement in the string.

Comment: perfect. I will accept this as soon as StackOverflow allows me.

Comment: Isn't that what the re.sub function is doing (or for that matter javscript strings)? Technically what that function is doing is (to put it in @KoliberServices words is: "break[ing] the string up into tokens and match[ing] and then reassembl[ing] it." Just thought I'd point that out. In both languages, strings are immutable.

Comment: In both languages strings are indeed immutable. However, in Java, you StringBuffers allow you to write better-performing string assembly code,  and turn it into a String at the end. I am not familiar how Python would do it, but I am sure the high wizards have thought of something. Also, doing it in place allows you to save memory. At start you have sourceStr. If you break it into tokens, you have tokens taking up memory. Assembling it together you have destStr. Doing it in place, you can avoid tokens because you can read positionally from srcString, saving some memory.